# Keras accuracy of only most certain predictions

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, artificial-intelligence

I am using keras to perform binary classification (single label, one or zero).

I would like to create a custom metric that takes the highest 10% from the predictions and calculates the accuracy of those.

So for example with the labels [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]

and the predictions [0.5, 0.7, 0.98, 0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 0.2, 0.1, 0.9, 0.8]

It only computes the accuracy of the 0.98 prediction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve my problem using this code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def topacc(y_true, y_pred):
  k = tf.cast(len(y_true) // 10, 'int64')
  y_true, y_pred = tf.transpose(y_true), tf.transpose(y_pred)
  return tf.keras.metrics.top_k_categorical_accuracy(y_true, y_pred, k=k)
```

This works as a full keras metric

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def accuracy_metric_fn(y_true, y_pred):
  l = len(y_pred) // 10
  top = tf.math.top_k(y_pred, l)
  y_pred = top.values
  y_true = tf.gather(y_true, top.indices)
  y_true = tf.cast(y_true, tf.float32)
  loss = tf.keras.metrics.binary_accuracy(
      y_true, y_pred)
  return loss

y_true = [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
y_pred = [0.5, 0.7, 0.98, 0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 0.2, 0.1, 0.9, 0.8]
print(accuracy_metric_fn(y_true, y_pred).numpy())
```

Comment: I still get an error when training with the metric:

Comment: InvalidArgumentError:  input must have at least k columns. Had 1, needed 4
  [[node TopKV2 (defined at <ipython-input-9-a88dcbc73e54>:7) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_33430]

Errors may have originated from an input operation.
Input Source operations connected to node TopKV2:
 functional_5/dense_5/Sigmoid (defined at <ipython-input-11-44811b9f549a>:2) 
 floordiv (defined at <ipython-input-9-a88dcbc73e54>:6)

Function call stack:
train_function